# How to implement onclick event only for current button?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to show/hide div with children on button click, but not other same divs in different parent blocks.
Sorry for my bad explanation and js knowledge, maybe the code can speak better:

```
for (a = 0; a < document.querySelectorAll("#hidereplies").length; a++) {
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll("#hidereplies")[a];
    btn.onclick = function () {
        for (var y = 0; y < document.querySelectorAll(".reply_comments").length; y++) {
            var reply = document.querySelectorAll(".reply_comments")[y];
            reply.style.display = (reply.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block');
        }
    };
}
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glebcha/yhtKa/3/).

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out is that you shouldn't call a function in the `for` declaration. Set the length to a variable. By doing this you are calling `document.querySelectorAll()` every iteration.

Comment: Yep, always use variables, but this time thought it would be better to define full query because I'm asking noob questions :) Thanks for advice, hope all javascript newbies will learn this lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you're doing wrong.

First, in your HTML, don't use an ID more than once. You've given your buttons the same ID.

Next, assign your querySelector results to an array and iterate the array.

Third, you need to scope your query. You're checking for elements on the `document` so everything gets pulled in rather than being scoped to the current div.

```
//note that I've changed from an ID to a class for your buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".hidereplies");

for (a = 0; a < buttons.length; a++) {
    var btn = buttons[a];
    btn.onclick = function (event) {
        var btn = event.currentTarget; //get the current button clicked
        var comments = btn.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".reply_comments"); //scope the search
        for (var y = 0; y < comments.length; y++) {
            var reply = comments[y];
            reply.style.display = (reply.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block');
        }
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="comments_list">
    <div class="comment_item">
        <div class="comment_body">test1 - comments</div>
        <input type="button" class="hidereplies" value="show replies" />
        <div class="reply_comments">
            <div class="comment_body">want to hide only current ".reply_comments"</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_item">
        <div class="comment_body">test2 - comments</div>
        <input type="button" class="hidereplies" value="show replies" />
        <div class="reply_comments">
            <div class="comment_body">but not all</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_item">
        <div class="comment_body">test3 - no comments</div>
        <div class="reply_comments"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yhtKa/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but didn't work. Here is full script http://jsfiddle.net/glebcha/uxMwX/ and again sorry for being asking like total noob.

Comment: Asking is fine, that's what this site is for. The problem isn't with the code, it's your markup. It's a bit difficult for me to understand the structure of your markup because there's a lot of useless markup there. Clean up the structure and try with just 2 or 3 comments. The most likely cause is that btn.parentNode needs to be modified to get the proper parent container.

Comment: @glebcha also, see if this is what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/uxMwX/1/ I noticed that the reply_comments is notw not on the same level as the button.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for sorting this out @JohnP! Many thanks to you and wish I had enough reputation points to give them all to you :)

Late night made me so stupid to miss the fact that I have to level up once again to get the exact element.